# Is there a (built-in) UPnP client in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, upnp

Older versions of Windows used to be able to detect a UPnP-enabled router and expose it as an “internet gateway” where you can manage the UPnP port forwarding assignments.

What happened to that functionality in Windows 10? If it’s no longer built-in, is there a 3rd-party alternative?

Comment: When I open Windows 10 network environment I still see see those UPnP devices. Why do you think this feature has been removed?

Comment: @Robert I somehow can't find them. Can you show me the steps?

Comment: Make sure you have configured your network connection as "Private" not "Public". The devices just show without having anything to configure.

Comment: @Robert My connection is already set as Private. And I also have Network discovery turned on already. I know that UPnP is working correctly on my Mikrotik router because, on the router's management UI, I can see other devices or services making port forwarding rules using UPnP.

Comment: A router is always the “internet gateway”, no connection to UPnP.

Comment: So you want me to install XP/7 to understand your question, rather than explain which functionality you're looking for?

Comment: @harrymc I just said in my question: the old "internet gateway" thing allows me to manage UPnP port forwarding assignments. I can't get the same functionality in Windows 10 for some reason.

Comment: Any router firmware can do that. Still unclear to me.

Comment: @harrymc the point is that it used to be possible to manage UPnP port forwarding assignments using a *built-in* Windows feature. I *don’t* want to go to my router’s UI to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Manually managing UPnP port forwarding assignments is a feature of the past. Windows 10 has an API for that, so almost all applications nowadays open
their own ports without user intervention.

If you have an older application and need to port-forward your own ports,
the only built-in tool you can use is
[netsh](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts)
with a syntax like:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4422 listenaddress=192.168.1.111 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.33
```

If `netsh` is not useful for your purpose, there are many free tools
for opening UPnP ports on the router.

Here is a small list:

- [UPnP Wizard](https://www.xldevelopment.net/upnpwiz.php)
- [Robusta Port Forwarder](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/robusta_port_forwarder.html)
- [Albertino Port Mapper](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/Albertino-Port-Mapper.shtml)
- [UPnP PortMapper](https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper)
  (requires Java)

I have not used any of these tools and cannot recommend one above the others.

Comment: Can you update how to specify nat router (which is relevant if behind several)?

Answer (score -1):

The best modern upnp port mapper in the year of 2023 is:

[UPnP Port Mapper](https://github.com/upnpportmapper/download)

It's the only professional portmapper there is, the other ones aren't.

Here is the download:

https://github.com/upnpportmapper/download

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).